# Ansible: how to automatically call dictionary keys in loop

Tags: ansible

as part ansible automation, there is a variable file being generated in below format and saved as `somedictvars.yml` and i am able to use looping if i specify each key separately in task.

But, since it's automatically generated and number of keys vary (sometimes it can have one employee or sometimes it may have more than one employee details.), i am looking for a way to specify only prefix of KEY used under loop.

`somedictvars.yml`

```
-  employee1:
    name: Martin D'vloper
    job: Developer
    skills:
      - python
      - perl
      - pascal
-  employee2:
    name: Tabitha Bitumen
    job: Developer
    skills:
      - lisp
      - fortran
      - erlang
```

my ansible playbook works as below, manually specifying each dict var key.

```
- name: include vars from YAML config files.
  include_vars: somedictvars.yml

- name: debug
  debug:
      msg: "{{ item.name }}"
  loop:
     - "{{ employee1 }}"
     - "{{ employee2 }}"
```

output:
TASK [debug]

```
*********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [UKXWD1EM01] => (item={u'skills': [u'python', u'perl', u'pascal'], u'job': u'Developer', u'name': u"Martin D'vloper"}) => {
    "msg": "Martin D'vloper"
}
ok: [UKXWD1EM01] => (item={u'skills': [u'lisp', u'fortran', u'erlang'], u'job': u'Developer', u'name': u'Tabitha Bitumen'}) => {
    "msg": "Tabitha Bitumen"
}
```

Please help how to use a common name under loop .. like `employee[0-9]` and if my file has 1 key, it will be printed in debug and if it has 3 keys, i will be printed only 3 Key['name'].

Else, please suggest if i can change file format to any other, to comply with ansible. so that looping can work automatically for any number of variable KEYs available inside the file.

Please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file and create the variable `employees`. The tasks

```
    - slurp:
        src: somedictvars.yml
      register: somedictvars
    - set_fact:
        employees: "{{ somedictvars.content|b64decode|from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        var: employees
```

give

```
    "employees": [
        {
            "employee1": {
                "job": "Developer", 
                "name": "Martin D'vloper", 
                "skills": [
                    "python", 
                    "perl", 
                    "pascal"
                ]
            }
        }, 
        {
            "employee2": {
                "job": "Developer", 
                "name": "Tabitha Bitumen", 
                "skills": [
                    "lisp", 
                    "fortran", 
                    "erlang"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

There are more options how to proceed.

---

1) Fit the dictionaries to the purpose. The tasks

```
    - set_fact:
        employees2: "{{ employees2|default([]) +
                        [{'employee': my_key.0}|combine(my_val.0)] }}"
      vars:
        my_key: "{{ item.keys()|list }}"
        my_val: "{{ item.values()|list }}"
      loop: "{{ employees }}"
    - debug:
        var: employees2
```

give

```
    "employees2": [
        {
            "employee": "employee1", 
            "job": "Developer", 
            "name": "Martin D'vloper", 
            "skills": [
                "python", 
                "perl", 
                "pascal"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "employee": "employee2", 
            "job": "Developer", 
            "name": "Tabitha Bitumen", 
            "skills": [
                "lisp", 
                "fortran", 
                "erlang"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Loop the list. For example

```
    - debug:
          msg: "{{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ employees2 }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": "Martin D'vloper"
    "msg": "Tabitha Bitumen"
```

---

2) Instead of changing the structure of the dictionaries it is possible to use [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter). For example

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ employees|json_query('[].*.name')|flatten }}"
```

gives the same result

```
    "msg": "Martin D'vloper"
    "msg": "Tabitha Bitumen"
```